# Android openGL ES 3 what is the alternative of Vector3f and Matrix4f classes?

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader, opengl-es-3.0

**In openGL**

- when using LWJGL, you will be able to create a transformation matrix like this:

  ```
  public static Matrix4f createTransformationMatrix(Vector3f translation,float rx,float ry,float rz,float scale ){

  Matrix4f matrix = new Matrix4f();
  matrix.setIdentity();
  //translate
  Matrix4f.translate(translation,matrix,matrix);

  //rotate
  Matrix4f.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(rx),new Vector3f(1,0,0) , matrix, matrix);
  Matrix4f.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(ry),new Vector3f(0,1,0) , matrix, matrix);
  Matrix4f.rotate((float)Math.toRadians(rz),new Vector3f(0,0,1) , matrix, matrix);

  //scale
  Matrix4f.scale(new Vector3f(scale,scale,scale),matrix,matrix);

  return matrix;

  }
  ```
- after that you are able to upload this tranformed matrix, to a uniform variable using this:

  ```
  FloatBuffer matrixBuffer = FloatBuffer.allocate(16); //means 16 elements in matrix 4x4

  protected void loadMatrix(int location , Matrix4f matrix){

      matrix.store(matrixBuffer);
      matrixBuffer.flip();
      glUniformMatrix4f(location,false,matrixBuffer);
  }
  ```

**What are Matrix4f and Vector3f:**

- Matrix4f: seems to be a 4x4 matrix, containing 16 float elements.
- Vector3f: seems to be a 3D vector containing 3 floats.

And these 2 classes seems to be only found in LWJGL.

**But I am using openGl ES 3 on android**

I cant find any classes in android built in like Matrix4f and Vector3f.

Do you know what should I do in android to implement same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use classes from android.renderscript:

```
import android.renderscript.Float3;
import android.renderscript.Matrix3f;
import android.renderscript.Matrix4f;
```

In OpenGL ES 2.0/3.0 for matrix transformations you can also use the static functions from the Matrix class:

```
import android.opengl.Matrix
...
protected val viewMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val projectionMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val modelMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val modelViewMatrix = FloatArray(16)
protected val mvpMatrix = FloatArray(16)
...
Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 4f,
        0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) // set camera position
...
Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far)
...
// move object up/down and left/right
Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, x, y, z) 
// angle and direction of rotation
Matrix.rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, angle, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f)
Matrix.scaleM(modelMatrix, 0, 4f, 4f, 4f) // scale object 
// matrix multiplication
Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, modelViewMatrix, 0)
...
// final mvp for shader
fun getMVPMatrixAsFloatBuffer(): FloatBuffer = Buffers.floatBuffer(mvpMatrix)
```